# MYSQL SUM of columns in joined table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to do the following query:

```
    SELECT
(
    SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
    FROM
    pl_invoices
    JOIN
    pl_invoice_articles
    ON
    pl_invoices.invoice_id = pl_invoice_articles.invoice_article_invoice_id
    WHERE
    pl_invoices.invoice_amount_paid = SUM(pl_invoice_articles.invoice_article_price)
) as 'Aantal Betaald'
```

So: I need to know how many invoices are paid, but the only way to know that is to make the sum of all the invoice articles and compare that to the total amount paid.

This query does not work and I don't know what i'm doing wrong. Is there anyone who can help me?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: please add your table definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use having clause instead of where

```
SELECT cnt as 'Aantal Betaald' from (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT, invoice_amount_paid  FROM  pl_invoices pl JOIN pl_invoice_articles pla
    ON     pl.invoice_id = pla.invoice_article_invoice_id
    having     pl.invoice_amount_paid = SUM(pla.invoice_article_price)
) tt  ;
```

Comment: This results in the following: Unknown column 'pl.invoice_amount_paid' in 'having clause', so I added invoice_amount_paid in the second select but then I get an empty value

Comment: Nevermind, it works with adding 'invoice_amount_paid', Thanks!

Comment: i think your pl_invoices table contain the column "invoice_amount_paid" ??

Comment: great if it works that's all please mark this as answered question

Comment: Will do in 1 minute! ;)

Comment: i think this will count the number of articles paid, but not the number of invoices paid, see it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c3b2/1 it returns 2 but it should return 1

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to this query to calculate the sum:

```
select
  invoice_article_invoice_id,
  SUM(invoice_article_price) as tot
from
  pl_invoice_articles
group by
  invoice_article_invoice_id
```

and join it as a subquery to the pl_invoices table:

```
select count(*)
from
  pl_invoices inner join (
    select
      invoice_article_invoice_id,
      SUM(invoice_article_price) as tot
    from
      pl_invoice_articles
    group by
      invoice_article_invoice_id
  ) s on pl_invoices.invoice_id = s.invoice_article_invoice_id
where
  pl_invoices.invoice_amount_paid = s.tot
```